# Managed Properties created for list column showing empty in Item Display Template

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, display-template, managed-property, sharepoint-search

Good Day! I have created a Description column in my list and created managed property with ows_Description as the crawled property. The column type is Multiple lines of Text. I am not able to retrive this in Item Display template. I am able to retrive a custom column Reference but not Description. Am I missing anything here. Could somebody help me explaining the concept considering me as a kid who started learning search in SharePoint. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

After creating new managed properties, please wait for some time so search crawl can run automatically in SharePoint online.

Please also check whether you could search successfully using "ManagedProperty:Value".

Note the property settings as shown below:

[image]

Here is an article about how to change an item display template to show values from custom managed properties for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/how-to-display-values-from-custom-managed-properties-in-search-resultsoption-1#how-to-change-an-item-display-template-to-show-values-from-custom-managed-properties---option-1

Comment: Hi Julie.. Thank you for the answer. I tried the search but it is not working for the new property name I created `NewDescription` but is working for `Description`. My doubt here is since i have added the crawled property `ows_Description` to the new property name, why is it not working and any idea or suggestion you have?

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of the managed property you created ?Since there is an OOB managed property called "Description", so it will work well.